# Magento 2.4.4 thumbnails doesn't show

Tags: gallery

i installed magento 2.4.4 but i can't see thumbnails on my website.

I followed a lot of suggestions on internet like disable old media gallery or type
php bin/magento media-gallery:sync
php bin/magento media-content:sync

and chmod etc but nothing works.

When i compile, i get this message :

Media files stored outside of 'Media Gallery Allowed' folders will not be available to the media gallery.

Someone could help me please ?

Thanks a lot by advance
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you get the following message when you run setup:upgrade

```
Media files stored outside of 'Media Gallery Allowed' folders will not be available to the media gallery.
Please refer to Developer Guide for more details.
```

This is not an error, but just some info message printed by the setup upgrade command.
Please see `\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UpgradeCommand::execute`

I'm guessing it was added by Adobe when they changed to the new Media Gallery which has an integration with Adobe Stock.
[Read here for more](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4409491698189-Stock-images-not-displayed-Adobe-Commerce-and-Magento-Open-Source-2-3-7-p2#:%7E:text=This%20is%20because%20the%20images,an%20allowed%20Media%20Gallery%20directory.).

As to your issue, the information you've provided are not enough to understand whats causing it, but will edit the answer if you provide more information.

Please see below some steps to debug.

1. Check for a specific SKU thumbnail image in the database

```sql
SELECT cpe.sku,
    cpe_varchar.value
FROM catalog_product_entity AS cpe
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar cpe_varchar ON cpe.row_id = cpe_varchar.row_id
    AND cpe_varchar.attribute_id = (
        SELECT attribute_id
        FROM eav_attribute
        WHERE attribute_code = 'thumbnail'
            AND entity_type_id = (
                SELECT entity_type_id
                FROM eav_entity_type
                WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
            )
    )
    AND cpe_varchar.store_id = 0
WHERE cpe.sku="your-sku";
```

If this returns no results on NULL, then probably the image was removed as a thumbnail in some way.

2. If the image is set, check for the file existence in the server.
3. If it does, check for the file permission and ownership. It should have the same user permissions as Magento so it is readable.